# problem in adding tortoise svn repo. on network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i created a repo as described [here](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html) repository is created and i can access it locally
( file///C:/SVN/MyProject/trunk) now i want to share it with other users on network i.e. LIKE
( svn//localhost( OR /IP)/SVN/MyProject/trunk) but not able to access it with ip/localhost

my svnserv.exe --daemon is running

please give me way how can i add it on network

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be `svn://localhost/SVN/MyProject/trunk`. Replace localhost by the IP address of the repo machine if you want to access it from another machine.

If you want another URL, then follow [these instructions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html).